# Invoking/Executing a function AFTER caller function finished or returned in FMX or System Library

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

TMessageManager's 'SendMessage' method does **NOT** invoke the 'Subscribed' (or associated callback) function **AFTER** the function that calls the 'SendMessage' is finished.

For a usable solution for this problem, I was thinking about using TTimer with least possible time interval (which is 1 millisecond) so that when you Enable the timer in the caller function, the OnTimer event of TTimer will have to be triggered **AFTER** the function that Enabled it. I think this is a kind of "slow" and ugly workaround to this problem.

Is there any Application-wide messaging facility in FMX or System Library that can invoke a callback function AFTER the caller function is finished or returned ? (Other application messages processed/invoked between them is also okey) This is for FMX or Multi-Device Cross Platform development by the way. Not specific to VCL or Windows Environment.

(What I really want, is to be able to send a message to the own application similar to the how Windows API function PostMessage behaves. The messages sended by PostMessage appear from windows procedure callback function after PostMessage function is returned.)

Answer (score 2):

`TMessageManager.SendMessage()` is synchronous.  For asynchronous sending, look at [`TThread.Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) if you are posting messages from a worker thread, or [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) if you are posting messages from the main UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, it worked using TThread::ForceQueue method on the main thread.  I used TThread::ForceQueue (0, pMyObj->ForceQueueOut);  line of code to trigger the function and the function implementation in my class was: void __fastcall MyClass::ForceQueueOut() { /* ... */ }